# How do you pass a State through a component, and than again through another component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx

Im trying to pass a state through a component(header), the useState const is created in the :root App page

```
function App() {

  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="global-container">
      <Header setOpen={setOpen}/>
      <DropdownMenu setOpen={setOpen}/>
      <PageRouter />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Inside the header, it calls another function which is a sub section of the header

```
export default function Header ({ SetOpen }) {

return (
    <div className="header-position">
        <div className="header-wrapper">

            <div className="header-left">
                <Menu icon={<RiMenu4Fill />} setOpen={setOpen} /> //for some reason it says setOpen is not defined
            </div>


please help me
```

Comment: you have a upper case typo in SetOpen in the props. Should be setOpen. Otherwise that is exactly how you pass state through components

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

`SetOpen` is capitalized in your header props